# Union collections only if second TSource is not Null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I have the following linq statement:

```
List<Type> allTypes = group.GetTypes().Union(group2.GetTypes()).ToList();
```

There might be a case when group2 is null which will throw me NullReferenceException

One way to solve this is to perform null check before, something like:

```
if (group2 != null)
{
    List<Type> allTypes = group.GetTypes().Union(group2.GetTypes()).ToList();
}
else 
{
   List<Type> allTypes = group.GetTypes();
}
```

but the problem is that I have many similar assignment for different types and don't want to do if statements for each of them in such a way, but I'd rather put null check in one line, something like:

```
 List<Type> allTypes = group.GetTypes().Union((if group2 != null)group2.GetTypes()).ToList();
```

but not sure how to do it with linq.

Comment: It's questions like these that make me anticipate the upcoming `?.` operator so much.

Comment: You might want to consider changing your design so that `group2` is never null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have here is not TSource being null; it's the object you want to get source from is null (`group2`).

You can always use `Enumerable.Empty` to save your magic one liners.

```
List<Type> allTypes = group.GetTypes().Union(group2 != null ? group2.GetTypes() : Enumerable.Empty<Type>()).ToList();
```

Or you can use a reusable `Union` overload:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Union<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    var set = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach (var s in source)
    {
       foreach (var item in s)
       {
           if (set.Add(item))
               yield return item;
       }
    }
}
```

Then your code turns to:

```
var allTypes = new [] { group, group2 }.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.GetTypes()).Union().ToList();
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can have more than two sequences forming a union.

Comment: Note that the `Union` method that you have would be noticeably more efficient by creating a `HashSet` and union-ing all of the sequences with it.  As it is, you're constantly building and then throwing away a hashset to represent the intermediate data set.

Comment: While you're right about the performance, `HashSet` would have a nasty side effect of rearranging the sequence. `Enumerable.Union` first returns elements from the first sequence (in order), then from the second.

Comment: And that behavior can be easily emulated.  Essentially your code would look exactly like the source code for `Union` except that instead of doing the code once for each set, you'd `foreach` over the two sets.  The meat of the code (outside the error checking and set creation) ends up becoming: `foreach(var sequence in source) if(sequence != null) foreach(var item in sequence) if(set.Add(item)) yield return item;`

Comment: `source.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct()` should be equivalent to your union method. The example code would simply become `.Where(x => x != null).SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Distinct()`

Comment: The null handling of your `Union` method is weird. If all elements are `null`, it'll return an empty sequence. If it contains both null and non-null elements, you get a null reference exception.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I was aware of the bug/feature (the original code should had a throw if a source was null). I agree and am in favour of consistent null handling.

Answer (score 3):

All you need here is a method to get the types of a group that can support a null parameter, since yours doesn't.  It's a pretty simple method to write:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> MyGetTypes(Group group)
{
    if(group == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<Type>();
    else
        return group.GetTypes();
}
```

(You can make it an extension method if you want)

You can now write your original code as:

```
var allTypes = MyGetTypes(group).Union(MyGetTypes(group2)).ToList();
```

---

We could also generalize this instead of making this method so specific, if we wanted.

```
public static TResult Use<TSource, TResult>(TSource source,
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector,
    TResult defaultValue = default(TResult))
{
    if (source == null)
        return defaultValue;
    else
        return selector(source);
}
```

This would let us write:

```
var allTypes = group.GetTypes()
    .Union(group2.Use(g => g.GetTypes(), Enumerable.Empty<Type>()))
    .ToList();
```

---

When C# 6.0 comes out and we get access to the `?.` operator you'd also be able to write the code out like so:

```
var allTypes = group.GetTypes()
    .Union(group2?.GetTypes() ?? Enumerable.Empty<Type>())
    .ToList();
```

This allows the null group to propagate to a null collection of types, rather than throwing, and then allows that null value to be substituted with an empty collection, which `Union` will support.  This operator is more or less a built in version of our `Use` method, but it allows us to avoid needing to use a lambda, making it noticeably more concise.

Answer (score 2):

The best I've found for putting a null check in one line is the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

```
List<Type> allTypes = group2 == null ? 
  group.GetTypes() 
  : group.GetTypes().Union(group2.GetTypes()).ToList();
```

Comment: that's a good solution, but was hoping that I can do something like @usr suggested.

Comment: @Stanislav You'll be able to once C# 6.0 comes out, as I show in my answer.  There is no way to do it currently.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of situation, I typically create a new extension method. E.g.:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SafeUnion<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source1, IEnumerable<T> source2)
{
    return source1 != null ?
        (source2 != null ? source1.Union(source2) : source1) : source2;
}
```

Or whatever specific logic makes the most sense in your case (the above will allow either enumerable to be null...you might want to allow only the second, for example).

Some curmudgeons may feel that the OP is incapable of adapting this idea to his own needs. I think he probably would have no trouble, and without declarations for the variables I can't show precisely what that would look like. But it would be something a *bit* like this:

```
public static List<Type> SafeUnion(this Group group1, Group group2)
{
    return (group2 != null ?
            group1.GetTypes().Union(group2.GetTypes()) : group1.GetTypes();
}
```

Of course, the `Group` type needs to be replaced by whatever the type of those variables actually is. This example also doesn't allow `group1` to be null. If that's required, presumably the reader can figure that change out on their own.

Comment: That makes total sense.  LINQ is already extension methods, so just add more.

Comment: But it doesn't address the question. The problem is not the sequence being null - the `group2` object is null. Also, your `SafeUnion` may return null, which isn't very LINQish.

Comment: As I wrote, the example can be adapted according to the OP's needs. Unfortunately, the OP did not provide a full code example, and without a proper declaration of the `group` and `group2` variables, it's not possible to write a code example that matches that exactly. As for returning `null`, well...it's not "LINQ-ish" to allow nulls in the extension methods in the first place, so what?